# Optical markup or character recognition of a graph in C#.Net

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, omr

No Idea with what to start in this case i have to extract the red block image from following tiff Image [image]

After extracting I have to read the graph and get output as follows :-
if 
1 - Off Duty
2 - Sleeper Berth
3 - Driving
4 - On Duty 
then following graph Should give as 22222243333131331332222 . what algorithm should be used I am using C# as programming Language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe MODI will help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29172/Converting-Images-to-Text-using-Office-2007-OCR-Op

**Updated:**

I think, you tried correctly way (AForge.net).
With AForge.Math.Geometry.SimpleShapeChecker class, you will find all rectangles. 
I will try again.

**Updated**

with Aforge.net you may compare two image. In your problem, you need compare with original empty cell(standard cell) each cell. And order by similarity, so first 24 cells are (that most not similar cells) that you need.

like this:

```
private void ProccessBitmap(Bitmap img, Bitmap original_cell)
    {
        int cellWidth = img.Width / 24;
        int cellHeight = img.Height / 4;
        IList<KeyValuePair<float, Rectangle>> table = new List<KeyValuePair<float, Rectangle>>();
        Bitmap cell;
        Rectangle rect;

        AForge.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new AForge.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 24; colIndex++)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(colIndex * cellWidth, rowIndex * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);

                cell = img.Clone(rect, img.PixelFormat);

                var matchings = tm.ProcessImage(original_cell, cell);
                table.Add(new KeyValuePair<float, Rectangle>(matchings[0].Similarity, rect));

                cell.Dispose();
            }
        }

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            gr.DrawRectangles(new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0f), table.OrderBy(a => a.Key).Take(24).Select(a => a.Value).ToArray());
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply Khurshid. Actually MODI is unable to read graph. it is showing garbage characters could you please help with another api or dll. One of the Api I discovered is Aforge.net but I could'nt make it out

Comment: can you browse original that tiff image, i want to try with  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C

Comment: I have sent image plz see if posible

Comment: did you find something @khurshid

Comment: Yes I find some solution, but not fully solution :)

Comment: Thanks for Solution @khurshid let me study your solution and hope for some idea tons of thanks for Helping. I am trying for solution and will get back if found perfect solution. if you find any solution let me know.

Comment: oh! no I can not compare images because the position of graph is not fixed it can be at any position in different scanned document and comparing in aforge is to slow.